# Converting a Yin Yang in XAML into C#

Tags: c#, xaml, geometry

I'm trying to draw a Yin Yang symbol using C# code because (to me) it feels like I have better control over what I'm doing and it also feels easier to manipulate it.

[image: Yin Yang Symbol from XAML]

I did succeed in drawing the symbol using XAML:

```
<Canvas Margin="50,50,900,1210" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Path Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="52" Canvas.Left="76.248" Height="244" Stretch="Uniform" Width="344.504" Fill="White">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50,0" IsFilled="True">
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="50, 50" Point="50, 100" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="25, 25" Point="50, 50" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="25, 25" Point="50, 0" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Path Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="52" Canvas.Left="14.748" Height="244" Stretch="Uniform" Width="344.504" Fill="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="50,0" IsFilled="True">
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="50, 50" Point="50, 100" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" />
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="25, 25" Point="50, 50" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Size="25, 25" Point="50, 0" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Path Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="96" Canvas.Left="194" Height="50" Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Fill="White" RenderTransformOrigin="1.126,-0.19">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="10, 10" RadiusX="5" RadiusY=" 5">
                <EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform CenterX="1" CenterY="10"/>
                        <RotateTransform CenterX="1" CenterY="10"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </EllipseGeometry.Transform>
            </EllipseGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Path Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="210" Canvas.Left="194" Height="50" Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Fill="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="1.126,-0.19">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry Center="10, 10" RadiusX="5" RadiusY=" 5">
                <EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform CenterX="1" CenterY="10"/>
                        <RotateTransform CenterX="1" CenterY="10"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </EllipseGeometry.Transform>

            </EllipseGeometry>
        </Path.Data>

    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

but when I try to draw it using code, I'm so confused as to why I'm not getting anything.

```
Path YinYangPathLeft=new Path();
YinYangPathLeft.Stroke=Brushes.Black;
YinYangPathLeft.StrokeThickness=5;

Path YinYangPath = new Path();
YinYangPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
YinYangPath.StrokeThickness = 5;

Point topPoint=new Point(50,0);
Point middlePoint = new Point(50, 50);
Point bottomPoint = new Point(50, 100);

//point start point, size, rotation angle, bool is large arc, sweep direction, bool isstroked

//left side of symbol
ArcSegment arcSegment1 = new ArcSegment();
ArcSegment arcSegment2 = new ArcSegment();
ArcSegment arcSegment3 = new ArcSegment();

//right side of symbol
ArcSegment arcSegment4 = new ArcSegment();
ArcSegment arcSegment5 = new ArcSegment();
ArcSegment arcSegment6 = new ArcSegment();

//start of the segments for Yin Yang
arcSegment1.Point = new Point(bottomPoint.X, bottomPoint.Y);
arcSegment1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
arcSegment1.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
arcSegment1.IsLargeArc = true;

arcSegment2.Point = new Point(middlePoint.X, middlePoint.Y);
arcSegment2.Size = new Size(50, 50);
arcSegment2.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
arcSegment2.IsLargeArc = true;

arcSegment3.Point = new Point(topPoint.X, topPoint.Y);
arcSegment3.Size=new Size(50,50);
arcSegment3.SweepDirection=SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
arcSegment3.IsLargeArc=true;

arcSegment4.Point = new Point(bottomPoint.X, bottomPoint.Y);
arcSegment4.Size = new Size(50, 50);
arcSegment4.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
arcSegment4.IsLargeArc = true;

arcSegment5.Point = new Point(middlePoint.X, middlePoint.Y);
arcSegment5.Size = new Size(50, 50);
arcSegment5.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
arcSegment5.IsLargeArc = true;

arcSegment6.Point = new Point(topPoint.X, topPoint.Y);
arcSegment6.Size = new Size(100, 100);
arcSegment6.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
arcSegment6.IsLargeArc = true;
//End of segments for Yin Yang


PathFigure YinYangFigureLeft=new PathFigure();
YinYangFigureLeft.StartPoint = topPoint;
YinYangFigureLeft.IsClosed = true;
YinYangFigureLeft.Segments.Add(arcSegment1);
YinYangFigureLeft.Segments.Add(arcSegment2);
YinYangFigureLeft.Segments.Add(arcSegment3);

PathGeometry YinYangGeometryLeft=new PathGeometry();
//YinYangGeometryLeft.AddGeometry(YinYangGeometryLeft);
YinYangGeometryLeft.Figures.Add(YinYangFigureLeft);

PathFigure YinYangFigureRight = new PathFigure();
YinYangFigureRight.StartPoint = topPoint;
YinYangFigureRight.IsClosed = true;
YinYangFigureRight.Segments.Add(arcSegment4);
YinYangFigureRight.Segments.Add(arcSegment5);
YinYangFigureRight.Segments.Add(arcSegment6);

PathGeometry YinYangGeometryRight = new PathGeometry();
//YinYangGeometryRight.AddGeometry(YinYangGeometryRight);
YinYangGeometryRight.Figures.Add(YinYangFigureRight);

GeometryGroup YinYangGeometryGroup=new GeometryGroup();
YinYangGeometryGroup.Children.Add(YinYangGeometryLeft);
YinYangGeometryGroup.Children.Add(YinYangGeometryRight);

//YinYangPath.Data = YinYangGeometryGroup;

GeometryDrawing YinYangGeometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing();
YinYangGeometryDrawing.Brush = Brushes.Black;
YinYangGeometryDrawing.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Yellow, 2);
YinYangGeometryDrawing.Geometry = YinYangGeometryGroup;

//DrawingGroup= Yin+Yang
DrawingGroup YinYangDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
YinYangDrawingGroup.Children.Add(YinYangGeometryDrawing);

//DrawingImage YinYangDrawingImage = new DrawingImage(YinYangGeometryDrawing);
DrawingImage YinYangDrawingImage = new DrawingImage(YinYangDrawingGroup);

YinYangTest.Source = YinYangDrawingImage;
```

I did also try using a Canvas and a StackPanel but still came up empty:

```
 /*
            Canvas YinYangCanvas = new Canvas();
            YinYangCanvas.Height = 200;
            YinYangCanvas.Children.Add(YinYangPath);
            this.Content = YinYangCanvas;
            */
            /*
            StackPanel YYSP = new StackPanel();
            YYSP.Children.Add(YinYangPath);
            this.Content = YYSP;
            */
```

Comment: Is the idea of easier control and manipulation due to thinking c# is actually superior for this experiment or inexperience with xaml? I only ask because I'm sitting here thinking exactly the opposite and I'd much rather use XAML, but then again it's not evident what you're overall trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity towards what you're trying to accomplish, I figured I would share how I would do it to maybe lend on the idea of how you might do it a bit easier your way also.

[image: xaml yin yang]

```
<Canvas Height="120" Width="120">

  <Path StrokeThickness="1.0" Stroke="Black" Fill="White" 
        Data="F1 M 89.591,29.017 C 89.591,52.492 72.658,59.419 56.110,59.419 C 41.871,59.419 30.711,75.583 30.711,87.512 C 30.711,102.873 41.258,112.244 51.418,117.710 C 54.023,118.063 56.679,118.261 59.381,118.261 C 91.899,118.261 118.261,91.899 118.261,59.381 C 118.261,29.019 95.279,4.033 65.764,0.851 C 82.748,7.431 89.591,19.831 89.591,29.017 Z"/>

  <Path Fill="Black" 
        Data="F1 M 0.500,59.381 C 0.500,89.196 22.668,113.820 51.418,117.710 C 41.258,112.244 30.711,102.873 30.711,87.512 C 30.711,75.583 41.871,59.419 56.110,59.419 C 72.658,59.419 89.591,52.492 89.591,29.017 C 89.591,19.831 82.748,7.431 65.764,0.851 C 63.667,0.624 61.538,0.500 59.381,0.500 C 26.862,0.500 0.500,26.861 0.500,59.381 Z"/>    

  <Path Fill="White" 
        Data="F1 M 53.233,30.594 C 53.233,27.065 56.094,24.206 59.621,24.206 C 63.148,24.206 66.009,27.065 66.009,30.594 C 66.009,34.122 63.148,36.981 59.621,36.981 C 56.094,36.981 53.233,34.122 53.233,30.594 Z"/>    

  <Path Fill="Black" 
        Data="F1 M 52.962,88.467 C 52.962,84.939 55.822,82.080 59.350,82.080 C 62.877,82.080 65.737,84.939 65.737,88.467 C 65.737,91.996 62.877,94.855 59.350,94.855 C 55.822,94.855 52.962,91.996 52.962,88.467 Z"/>

</Canvas>
```

Alternatively if you just wanted to use arc segments, I'd start with one ellipse, and draw just one side on top of it with arc segment. As for why your code doesn't produce anything, I'd ask if you get any kind of errors and where you have [PaintEventArgs or CreateGraphics method or a Graphics Object etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx) which would give a place to produce it.

Comment: I'm new to 2D graphics. I was watching a video on how to do graphics in WPF. As for the code that you put on there, I have no idea what all the numbers represent. Can that even be converted into codebind? I do apologize for my ignorance. 

In regards to your questions, I'm not even sure how to respond to them. @Chris

Comment: No worries man, can't apologize for stuff you don't know yet. I'd go check out the link at the bottom of the answer I posted. The numbers are just [Path Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data(v=vs.110).aspx) and could be, but that's why using xaml and designer tools like Blend and Illustrator make it far easier to work with than doing it all by hand in the codebehind.

Comment: I say easier to manipulate because I want to add additional code so that I can use GUI to manipulate size,  color, rotation,  etc

Comment: Huh, I guess those parts come down to preference, I'm still thinking that's all easier with mostly (if not all) xaml, but I'm a xaml fan so my opinion may be biased.

Comment: I kind of see what you mean in regards to the GUI because when I drag-and-drop, the GUI's code gets generated in the XAML code.

Comment: But I want to be able to SEE and make the code rather than having computer-generated code. I've had a lot of experience with C++ so I guess that's why I prefer codebind. So is there a simple way to connect a textbox to the YinYang through an event handler?

This is a tangent, but the point is that I want to convert the example you gave into codebind to see what each line is **doing**. I understand codebind better than XAML.@chris

Comment: Oh definitely agree that you don't want to just throw around stuff in the designer to generate code, it's a mess doing that. However it is a very effective and time saving way for certain tasks like making shape/image type artifacts. If you're getting into the MVVM type stuff though, there's distinct reasoning behind the detachment of procedural and presentation layer code, hence the c# and xaml as opposed to just c#. Give me an example of what you would like to do with your yin yang and I'll throw one back. :)

Comment: Ok, so the Yin Yang has a distinct size and is an ellipse (circle to be precise). Every circle has it's own radius and center. One example would be to use 3 textboxes to output its current location on the screen and the radius. And when the user enters a number to change either it's x or y coordinate or its radius, the Yin Yang moves/changes accordingly.